# Calling with Arguments versus using Globals in C

Tags: c, assembly, arguments

I have a decent understanding of x86 assembly and i know that when a function is called all the arguments are pushed onto the stack.

I have a function which basically loops through a 8 by 8 array and calls some functions based on the values in the array. Each of these function calls involves 6-10 arguments being passed. This program takes a very long time to run, it is a Chess AI, but this function takes 20% of the running time.

So i guess my question is, what can i do to give my functions access to the variables they need in a faster way?

```
int row,col,i;  
determineCheckValidations(eval_check, b, turn);
int * eval_check_p = &(eval_check[0][0]);

for(row = 0; row < 8; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < 8; col++, eval_check_p++){
        if (b->colors[row][col] == turn){
            int type = b->types[row][col];
            if (type == PAWN)
                findPawnMoves(b,moves_found,turn,row,col,last_move,*eval_check_p);
            else if (type == KNIGHT)
                findMappedNoIters(b,moves_found,turn,row,col,*move_map_knight, 8, *eval_check_p);
            else if (type == BISHOP)
                findMappedIters(b,moves_found,turn,row,col,*move_map_bishop, 4, *eval_check_p);
            else if (type == ROOK)
                findMappedIters(b,moves_found,turn,row,col,*move_map_rook, 4, *eval_check_p);
            else if (type == QUEEN)
                findMappedIters(b,moves_found,turn,row,col,*move_map_queen, 8, *eval_check_p);
            else if (type == KING){
                findMappedNoIters(b,moves_found,turn,row,col,*move_map_king, 8, *eval_check_p);
                findCastles(b,moves_found,turn,row,col);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all the code can be found @ https://github.com/AndyGrant/JChess/tree/master/_Core/_Scripts

A sample of the profile:

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 20.00      1.55     1.55  2071328     0.00     0.00  findAllValidMoves
 14.84      2.70     1.15 10418354     0.00     0.00  checkMove
 10.06      3.48     0.78  1669701     0.00     0.00  encodeBoard
  7.23      4.04     0.56 10132526     0.00     0.00  findMappedIters
  6.84      4.57     0.53  1669701     0.00     0.00  getElement
  6.71      5.09     0.52 68112169     0.00     0.00  createNormalMove
```

Comment: What makes you think it is the argument passing that is causing the performance issues? Could be many other things.

Comment: Could this function be inlined? that would remove a lot of stack handling, and maybe keep some of the arguments as registers...

Comment: What makes you think that passing the arguments is your performance bottleneck? Have you profiled your code? How? With what? Have you tried in-lining it? What are your arguments? A handful of integers? Or are you passing an enormous struct by value? What else happens in the function?

Comment: have you tried to pass variables 'by address' as pointers? - You could also put all the arguments into a structure and pass that by address

Comment: @AlanAu the function only contains a for loop and the function calls. i dont know what else it could be.

Comment: @IskarJarak i have profiled it, and 20% of run time is spent in this one function. The arguments are all either integers or pointers. I will edit my question with the code.

Comment: @AndrewGrant "only a loop and the function calls". Famous last words :-) Guessing is probably not a good way to go about this. Profile your code more deeply (not just at the function level).

Comment: @AndrewGrant 20% of the run time, but what % of call count? And is that self time or total time? And yeah, a loop, branching, and function calls ... that's _plenty_ of stuff going on.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information. If the arguments are not the bottle neck, what else could i improve upon to make it faster?

Comment: @AndrewGrant [You even have a malloc and a copy loop in that fn](https://github.com/AndyGrant/JChess/blob/fc85bb6ca5f3b6cf1e684e2fc138cefedf725d2a/_Core/_Scripts/Engine.c#L138) Definitely try profiling more deeply.

Comment: None of the functions you're calling look so tiny that parameter passing could possibly be a substantial portion of their cost.

Comment: @IskarJarak I seriously underestimated the time spent copying and mallocing. Upon splitting the function apart, 13% of runtime was spent in the malloc and copy section, while 7% was spent in the function i was concerned about. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: @AndrewGrant There's some famous saying about how programmers almost always guess incorrectly about where their program slowdowns are so we should always measure instead of assuming we know what is happening. That said, anything involving allocations, frees, or copying is a often good place to start looking. (And better data structure/algorithm design can help eliminate some of that.)

Comment: Whether or not the arguments are on the stack entirely depends on the calling convention.  While *cdecl* specifies sending arguments on the stack, GCC, as an example, can also use *fastcall* which will send the first two arguments that can be sent via register in ECX and EDX.  Microsoft X64 conventions send as many as 4 integer values in registers.  My point is that you cannot be certain that the arguments are on the stack.

Comment: Within your AI functions, you are mallocing and freeing fixed (small) size buffers.  Try turning those into stack allocations and this may remove quite a bit of your memory allocation overhead.  Ugh.  You are also using bubble sort.  Don't do that for any amount of data over 5 or 6 entries...

Comment: Not all of the function parameters are passed on the stack.  Depends on the compiler and platform.  The preference is to pass parameters through *registers*.  The parameters that are not passed in registers are passed on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You have performed good work on profiling.  You need to take the function with the worst case and profile it in more detail.

You may want to try different compiler optimization settings when you profile.

Try some common optimization techniques, such as loop unrolling and factoring out invariants from loops.

You may get some improvements by designing your functions with the processor's data cache in mind.  Search the web for "optimizing data cache".

If the function works correctly, I recommend posting to CodeReview@StackExchange.com.

Don't assume anything.